# How to check system process battery usage information on iOS 8?

Tags: jailbreak, ios

With iOS 8, It was made possible to get relevant battery usage for applications on iOS. Is there any way to find the battery usage of the system processes on iOS 8?
I'm looking for Jailbreak tweaks or Diagnostic tools because there aren't any other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DetailedBatteryUsage** Cydia tweak from the BigBoss repo shows the battery usage for system processes. It integrated right into the `Battery Status` tab inside settings and throws in a neat battery life cycle graph for the last seven days and also displays information about active usage/background usage.

[image]

Comment: I installed it on iOS 8/iPhone5. I see the picture on the left, but I don't see any of the items on the right. I see two lines beneath the "Background Usage": "Hide Daemons" and "Save For Demo". Tapping "Hide Daemons" reloads and flips it to "Show Daemons" but otherwise no other change.

Comment: @frakman1If you have an iOS12 device. This tweak is no longer required.

Comment: How to be able to see battery usage for ANY indicated period of time - let's say, latest X hours?? Is there any tweak for that? There is no much use to look at latest 24 hours, if, for instance, there was intensive battery drain at my device for last night and i want to find a guilty...